# Edit session data of another client with gin-contrib

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using go-gin as my framework in my go project. When I first started this project I came across [gin-gonic/contrib](https://github.com/gin-gonic/contrib) for middlewares so I started to using session middleware from there. Currently I'm using redis to store session data which works perfectly fine but for a feature I have to edit my redis key which I couldn't make work.

In this project I use a shared database(MySQL). I have another web server(php) that writes data into this database and go is being used mostly to show these data. In this database I store subscriber details such as username, password, email etc.

I need to update what I store inside redis about my subscribers. For example Subscription End Date(subEndDate) and it has to be triggered from PHP. So far everything is okay, once the admin update something about one of the subscribers the PHP triggers an endpoint(update-subscriber) so that my go code can update the redis key about that subsriber(which is what I couldn't make work). Normally what I would do is this

`session := sessions.Default(c)`

and then just session.set or session.get to retrieve or set data about this subscriber. It works fine but in this case the caller is not the client itself but my PHP server so when I use the code above it doesn't give me the session of a client I want. Is there a way to overcome this problem? I can pass the header value of my session data but I couldn't find a way to retrieve that specific session inside my go code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the gin sessions package: [github.com/gin-contrib/sessions](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-contrib/sessions). This seems to use the gorilla sessions package under the hood: [github.com/gorilla/sessions](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/sessions)

If you look at the [sessions.Store interface](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/sessions#Store) you'll see that Redis and other session storage methods take a `*http.Request` and return a session, so as far as I can tell there is no easy way for you to query for another users session through the session library using this interface.

```golang
type Store interface {
    // Get should return a cached session.
    Get(r *http.Request, name string) (*Session, error)

    // New should create and return a new session.
    //
    // Note that New should never return a nil session, even in the case of
    // an error if using the Registry infrastructure to cache the session.
    New(r *http.Request, name string) (*Session, error)

    // Save should persist session to the underlying store implementation.
    Save(r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter, s *Session) error
}
```

The redis storage seems to be provided by [github.com/boj/redistore](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/boj/redistore) and similarly there seems to be no way to access a session without first providing an http request.

It does look like the session is stored as redis value with a prefix [like this:](https://github.com/boj/redistore/blob/cd5dcc76aeff9ba06b0a924829fe24fd69cdd517/redistore.go#L339)

```
    _, err = conn.Do("SETEX", s.keyPrefix+session.ID, age, b)
```

Which means if you wanted to make a fake http request using `http.NewRequest` you might technically be able to make a fake cookie with the session id you're looking for and get the session that way. That might be challenging and fragile.

Generally I would maybe suggest not storing mutable state in your sessions and instead check your datastores directly when the user is making a request. You are using session data stored in redis, but maybe you can stick the data you expect to update in redis with its own key and get/set it as you need and not access the data through this sessions interface.